# Blazor WASM crashes when importing a JS module that contains imports

Tags: javascript, firebase, blazor-webassembly

I import the module via

```
public static async Task ImportModuleAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await JSHost.ImportAsync("Firebase", "/js/Firebase.js");
            IsModuleImported = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            string msg = ex.Message;
            JSTools.Debug(msg);
        }
    }
```

And this is the calling bit:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await JSTools.ImportModuleAsync();
    }
```

If the js file only contains `export funcion blabla(){return "bla";}` it works as expected. But I'm connecting to firebase, and I need to import some stuff like

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";

export function blabla(){
   return "bla";
}
/*etc*/
```

The very moment I include the import in my module, the `ImportAsync` method crashes the system, and it exits with error code 0xfffffff and no further explanation.

What's the expected way to include this kind of JS?

NOTE: If I run it with no debugger (Ctrl+F5 instead of just F5) It does work, it does not shut down. But obviously, I need to develop with debug capabilities.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor, but have you tried downloading [https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js) locally and importing from your file system? If so, does that also cause a crash?

Comment: yes I tried. When doing that, it complains about a missing .js.map. When downloading also this, it ends up doing the same. I have the impression somehow blazor doesn't allow importing stuff dynamically. But I don't know how to enforce all imports at init.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't understand static imports, but have you tried dynamic import via the [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) function? Try using it with top-level await or by wrapping the whole thing in an async IIFE.

Comment: I've no clue about JS. I'm a C# coder forced to interact with JS for this Firebase connection. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I left an answer that elaborates.

Answer (score 0):

In `/js/Firebase.js`, try writing:

```js
const { initializeApp } = await import("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js");

export function blabla(){
   return "bla";
}
/*etc*/
```

That is known as a *dynamic import* in JavaScript. Again, I'm not familiar with how Blazor works, but the [`ImportAsync` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.javascript.jshost.importasync?view=net-7.0#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20host%27s%20dynamic%20import%20API) seems to mention using it, so I'm just tossing out ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this. No difference whatsoever :(

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are misusing the API, so if it's still causing a hard failure, that sounds more like a framework bug than your bug. Make sure you are using the latest stable version of Blazor. Otherwise, the last thing I'd recommend to try to find a workaround is to [search Githhub](https://github.com/search?q=JSHost.ImportAsync&type=code) to see what others did. Good luck!